# How to modify pipfile to install packages from other source?

Tags: pipenv, paddle-paddle, pipfile

I'm trying to install paddlepaddle-gpu == 2.5.1.post120.

Before this issue was raised, I downloaded this dependency with such command:

```
python3 -m pip install paddlepaddle-gpu==2.5.1.post120 -f https://www.paddlepaddle.org.cn/whl/linux/mkl/avx/stable.html
```

which means, I have to exclusively use this command to install this package when I can use simply a `pipenv install`  to install other dependencies.

So I tried to modify pipfile like this:

adding:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[[source]]
url = "https://www.paddlepaddle.org.cn/whl/linux/mkl/avx/stable.html"
verify_ssl = true
name = "paddle"

[[packages]]
...
...
paddlepaddle-gpu = {version='2.5.1.post', index='paddle'}

...
```

but when I ran `pipenv install` , full error occurred like:

```
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.reporter:Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement(
'paddlepaddle-gpu==2.5.1.post120'), None)
CRITICAL:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.factory:Could not find a version that satisfies the 
requirement paddlepaddle-gpu==2.5.1.post120 (from versions: none)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 397, in 
resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 174, in 
_add_to_criteria
    raise RequirementsConflicted(criterion)
pipenv.patched.pip._vendor.resolvelib.resolvers.RequirementsConflicted: Requirements conflict: 
SpecifierRequirement('paddlepaddle-gpu==2.5.1.post120')
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", 
line 92, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 546, in 
resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 399, in 
resolve
    raise ResolutionImpossible(e.criterion.information)
pipenv.patched.pip._vendor.resolvelib.resolvers.ResolutionImpossible: 
[RequirementInformation(requirement=SpecifierRequirement('paddlepaddle-gpu==2.5.1.post120'), parent=None)]
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 445, in resolve
    results = resolver.resolve(constraints, check_supported_wheels=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", 
line 101, in resolve
    raise error from e
pipenv.patched.pip._internal.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for 
paddlepaddle-gpu==2.5.1.post120
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 675, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 661, in main
    _main(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 645, in _main
    resolve_packages(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 612, in resolve_packages
    results, resolver = resolve(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 592, in resolve
    return resolve_deps(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 897, in resolve_deps
    results, hashes, internal_resolver = actually_resolve_deps(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 670, in actually_resolve_deps
    resolver.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 447, in resolve
    raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure: [31m[1mERROR[0m: [33mNo matching distribution found for 
paddlepaddle-gpu==2.5.1.post120[0m
✘ Locking Failed!
⠇ Locking...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pipenv", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/cli/options.py", line 58, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs, windows_expand_args=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 209, in install
    do_install(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/routines/install.py", line 164, in do_install
    do_init(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/routines/install.py", line 648, in do_init
    do_lock(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/routines/lock.py", line 65, in do_lock
    venv_resolve_deps(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 838, in venv_resolve_deps
    c = resolve(cmd, st, project=project)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 707, in resolve
    raise RuntimeError("Failed to lock Pipfile.lock!")
RuntimeError: Failed to lock Pipfile.lock!
```

regardless of the details, I know this means it did not find the dependency I want.

Probably what I wrote in pipfile is wrong, so I wonder how can I realize downloading this package through pipenv install.

Also, I have visited [source of my package](https://www.paddlepaddle.org.cn/whl/linux/mkl/avx/stable.html), finding all wheel files.

How can I make it?

（sorry for too much paste as I want to show you full message to make sure not missing anything)